# Let $M = \operatorname{cok}(\phi)$ where $\phi: \mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}^3$. Express $M$ as a direct sum of cyclic modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}^3$ be given by the matrix $A$ below. $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 4\\ 2 & 4 & 6 \\ 2 & 6 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$$ If $M = \operatorname{cok}(\phi)$, the problem is to express $M$ as a direct sum of cyclic modules.

I'm pretty sure $M$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. To solve this, I use the method laid out and justified in Dummit and Foote's exercises 17-19 in chapter 12.1.

If $M = \mathbb{Z}^3/\operatorname{im}(\phi)$ is the cokernel, then we may take $A$ to be the *relations matrix* of $M$. By the quoted exercise, we may apply row and column operations to $A$ to produce other relations matrices for $M$, so once we reduce $A$ to a diagonal matrix, we're done.

This can be done by the following row operations. $$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 4\\ 2 & 4 & 6 \\ 2 & 6 & 8
\end{bmatrix} \stackrel{R'_2 = R_2 - R_1}\to\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 4\\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 6 & 8
\end{bmatrix} \stackrel{R'_3 = R_3 - R_1}\to \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 4\\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 4 & 4
\end{bmatrix}  \stackrel{R_3' = R_3 - 2R_2}\to \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 2 & 4\\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \stackrel{R'_1 = R_1 - R_2}\to \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \stackrel{C'_3 = C_3 - C_2}\to \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \stackrel{C'_3 = C_3 - C_1}\to \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

This then gives a row/collumn reduction of $A$ to $$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$ which is precisely the relations matrix of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus 2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Is this correct?

Thanks!

EDIT 2: Apperently this is just the smith normal form, which is more general. In this case, I'm asking if my reasoning/smith normal form is correct. It was not before this edit, since my first row operation was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smith Normal Form and isomorphism type of cokernel look good. You can do a sanity check by considering the rank of the same matrix over $\mathbb Q$. The first two columns are linearly independent so you expect two torsion summands (possibly zero), and the last column is the sum of of the first two so the rank of the free part will be 1.

Can you also find an explicit basis in $\mathbb Z^3$ decomposing into kernel and cokernel (in an appropriate sense)? I would consider this part of "expressing as a direct sum", to not only identify isomorphism type but also give the explicit isomorphism. It can be determined via the row and column operations you already found. (This is also frequently needed e.g. if you study homology.)